# Twitter bootstrap tooltip and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, capybara

I'm running capybara and I keep getting this error bellow

```
✔  When I visit the agreement templates page 
!  And I follow "New Agreement Template"
~  And I fill out and submit the form                
~  Then I should see the new agreement template      
~  And I should be on the agreement template         

no link with title, id or text 'New Agreement Template' found
```

At the page tooltip has changed the "title" to "data-original-title" so the test can't find the "New Agreement Template".

I tried to change my test from

```
click_link('New Agreement Template')
```

to

```
find('#new-agreement').click_link('New Agreement Template')
```

adding the new-agreement as an ID but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying id of link in `click_link` method or try using something like `find('#new-agreement').click`

Comment: find('#new-agreement').click did the trick. thanks. Now I'll have to add an id to all the Create links

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `find('a[data-original-title="New Agreement Template"]').click`. (This worked for me in a similar situation.)